# How to import a package's dependency when using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I started a new Xcode Project. I imported a package using Swift Package Manager (e.g. [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick)).

I see Quick in the sidebar in Xcode.

I can now use Quick by first importing it:

```
import Quick
```

Everything works great with Quick.

---

I noticed that in the sidebar of Xcode, when I imported Quick, it automatically imported its dependencies (e.g. [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble)).

I assumed I could start using this dependency by importing it, however that lead to an error:

```
import Quick
import Nimble // ❌ No such module 'Nimble'
```

If I try omitting the `import` and just using a line of code from Nimble directly, I get an error as well:

```
expect(1 + 1).to(equal(3)) // Use of unresolved identifier 'expect'
```

How do I use Nimble in my project?

---

I'm guessing one way to resolve this is to explicitly add the Nimble package via Swift Package Manager too.

However, this seems wrong because:

1. I already have the source code for Nimble in my Xcode project
2. I don't want version mismatches between the explicit Nimble version that I get from Swift Package Manager, and the implicit Nimble I get from Quick.

How do I import a package's dependency when using Swift Package Manager?

Answer (score 1):

To use Nimble in your project, you have to install it in the same way as Quick, using the SPM. and you can import Quick in your class

1- The SPM only downloads the dependencies once, obviously of the same version or range.

2- You must control the version, setting the dependencies in the same range of versions.

Answer (score 0):

Swift package manifest has [product](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#product) field that can be used by library authors to declare build artifacts available to client:

> A package product defines an externally visible build artifact that’s available to clients of a package. The product is assembled from the build artifacts of one or more of the package’s targets

Whenever you are using a package you have the choice of importing targets that are used by these declared products. Let's suppose you have packege `A` which has product `B` and in product `B` targets `C` and `D` are exposed, when using `A` you can import `C` and `D`.

Now, Let's suppose package `A` uses package `E`'s target `F` and `G` in `C` and `D` respectively. In this scenario using package `A` also makes `F` and `G` from package `E` available to your project.

Now let's consider your scenario: you are using package `Quick`'s product `Quick` which exposes target `Quick` and you can import `Quick` without any issue. Although package `Quick` is using package `Nimble` internally in its test targets it doesn't use `Nimble` in `Quick` target which is what the package exposes publicly and you are using. To use `Nimble` you have explicitly add `Nimble` package.

> However, this seems wrong because:
>
> 1. I already have the source code for Nimble in my Xcode project
> 2. I don't want version mismatches between the explicit Nimble version that I get from Swift Package Manager, and the implicit Nimble I get from Quick.

I would say this behavior is correct and should be expected. Dependency managers allow dependency authors to specify their dependecy with proper constraints and author of `Quick` has specified that their public target `Quick` doesn't have any dependency on package `Nimble` and any of its targets. This gives you the flexibility of independently choosing version constraints of packages `Quick` and `Nimble` which you would expect since their author has told SPM that they are independent.